# console.log messages getting logged inconsistently in react.js when using dynamic import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hey everyone i am observing this strange behavior in my react app created via CRA(create-react-app) where the console log messages i am trying to log are getting logged inconsistently and sometimes not at all here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class Dynamic extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { module: null };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      console.log('in comp mount')
      alert("in comp mount")
    const { path } = this.props;
    import(`${path}`)
      .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))
 }
  render() {
      console.log('in render')
      alert("in render")
    const { module: Component } = this.state; // Assigning to new variable names @see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
    return(
      <div>
        {Component && <Component />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Dynamic path='./FirstComponent' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Note that every time the alerts are getting hit and displayed in browser but the console messages are getting logged very inconsistently and the message in componentDidMount() function isn't getting printed at all.  i tried the same thing with a bare bones standard create-react-app project and it displays the messages correctly so i am guessing it has something to do with  dynamic import

Answer (score 0):

Do **not call setState in componentDidMount(), this a lint in eslint, refer to [this link](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md) for details.

> "react/no-did-mount-set-state"

By default this rule forbids any call to this.setState in componentDidMount outside of functions.

The following patterns are considered warnings:

```
var Hello = createReactClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({
      name: this.props.name.toUpperCase()
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>;
  }
});
```

**Therefore follow the below code snippet pattern instead**

```
var Hello = createReactClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.onMount(function callback(newName) {
      this.setState({
        name: newName
      });
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>;
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer can you please tell me exactly why my console message is'nt getting logged at all in componentDidMount function?

Comment: Can you try remove the setState() out of the cdm and retry() to see the results?

Comment: i just removed setState from cdm and simply placed a log there the result is all alerts are still getting hit but no message is getting logged not even the in render ones.

Comment: remove alert() which blocks/interrupts the life cycles, just keep console.log

Comment: same result no messages getting logged